# Prolog: multiply list members with the previous member

Tags: prolog

```
%Multiply every list Element with his previous Elemennt.
%First Number stays as it is!
% Example list [1,2,3,4,5,6] becomes [1,2,6,12,20,30].

%my solution trying

vormulti1([],[]).
vormulti1([Kopf|Rest], [Neu|Rest2]) :-
   Neu is Kopf2 * Kopf,
   vormulti1(Rest, Rest2),
   Kopf2 is Kopf.
```

The problem is the previous member. I tried ist with the Kopf2 variable, but it doesn't work, cause it is not instanced at the first list element.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use Kopf2, since you do not have it in the formula, you cannot pass it to the recursion the way you'd like to. The variables are local to the particular formula. You need to get that other element through the arguments, for example like this:

```
vormulti1([],[]).
vormulti1([X],[X]).
vormulti1([X,Y|Z],[X|W]) :- vormulti2(X,[Y|Z],W).

vormulti2(X,[],[]).
vormulti2(X,[Y|Z],[V|W]) :- V is X * Y, vormulti2(Y,Z,W).
```

another possibility is that you reverse the list first (which is an efficient operation), and then it is easier to handle the end of the list:

```
vormulti1(X,Y) :- reverse(X,Z), vormulti2(Z,W), reverse(W,Y).
vormulti2([],[]).
vormulti2([Kopf], [Kopf]).
vormulti2([Kopf,Kopf2|Rest], [Neu|Rest2]) :- Neu is Kopf2 * Kopf, vormulti2([Kopf2|Rest], Rest2).
```

Good luck.

Comment: Good answer, except that `[Kopf | [Kopf2 | Rest]]` should really be written as `[Kopf, Kopf2 | Rest]`.

Comment: Thank you Isabelle. Yes. It shows the structure, doesn't it? :-), but you are right, this is more concise, I have edited the answer.

Comment: You are welcome! At StackOverflow, when you are satisfied with some answer to your question, you can accept it by clicking the green tick on the left. It will give you some bonus, and it will motivate the person who answered your question to help somebody else next time. It will also make it easier for other users and search engines to find working answers to questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
vormulti1([],[]).

vormulti1([X|[Y]], [X,Z]):- Z is X*Y,!.

vormulti1([H|[H2|T2]],Z) :-
    vormulti1([H2|T2], [_|T3]),!,
    Z2 is H2 * H,
    append([H,Z2], T3, Z).

vormulti1([X],[X]).
```

Comment: In its current state this is not a very good answer: Too many cuts in a predicate that doesn't need any, bad list syntax (use `[X, Y]` instead of `[X | [Y]]`, use `[H, H2 | T2]` instead of `[H | [H2 | T2]]`), unclear ordering of clauses (0 elements, 2 elements, more than 2 elements, 1 element). Please improve your answer, it will be much more useful!